# Android monkeyrunner - check if screen contains an image or specific color

Tags: android, image-processing, adb, monkeyrunner, genymotion

I have an android app which I wanted to automate/stress-test.
I made image-based automation script in SCAR Divi 
and run it against my app installed on Bluestacks.
I want to change it to Genymotion, because Bluestacks is too slow.

I already have the environment set up 
(genymotion+image with my app +adb installed and working).
I rewrited my script in python and used it in MonkeyRunner, but...

Besides sending gestures, clicks and waits, 
I am missing the image recognition functionality.
I found out that I can compare 2 screen shots with ImageMagic, but that's not what I need.

I need to check whether a certain button, or at least if a specific color is on the screen.
Anyone could point me into right direction with this?

I'd be really grateful for some examples :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**MonkeyRunner** does indeed offer pretty decent image based test methods. I will show you below how to take a **sub-image** from the currently displayed screen of your device. Then you can save this sub-image and/or compare with a **reference image**

First you need to take a screenshot of the current screen of your device

```
# Take a screenshot
image = device.takeSnapshot()
```

Then you can take a sub-image. For example, this sub-image could be a button on a certain screen to verify that the button exists on that screen. To be able to do that you can use the method below. The tuple (0, 0, 50, 100) below is only an example. You should provide your own. Basically it is (x, y, w, h) of the desired sub-image.

```
# Take the sub-image
sub_image = image.getSubImage((0, 0, 50, 100))
```

After that step, you can save the image and/or compare with a reference image. To compare with a reference image you can do as shown below:

```
# Load the reference image for comparison
reference = MonkeyImage.loadFromFile(PATH_TO_REFERENCE_IMAGE)

if not sub_image.sameAs(reference, 0.9):
       print "Images do not match!"
       # do something
```

0.9 is the acceptance level. If the two images match 90% or above, it will be considered as PASSED

Hope this helps. Do let me know if you encounter any problems!

Comment: Hello gbudan. A huge thanks for your reply. This is good, but only if you want to check whether a particular square with specified coords is the same as the reference image. I will definitely use it to check on static elements (like buttons). However, I also need to check whether a certain bitmap (or at least a certain color) is a part of that screenshot and it can be positioned anywhere on it.

Comment: Ok @user2192002, in that case you can make use of `getRawPixelInt(x, y)` method. Let's say you are looking for a **yellow** colour line that can be anywhere on the screen. To simplify, let's say this line is horizontal and its width is the same as your screen width. So, what you can do is, first take a screenshot and then, take one pixel at a time from this screenshot all the way from top of the screen to the bottom in a while loop. When `getRawPixelInt(x, y)` method finds a yellow pixel, that means you have found where the line is. You can implement the same logic for other situations too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply gbudan. I will try to implement and test this on Monday!

Comment: Is it just me or does MonkeyImage no longer have any way to load an image from file?

Comment: The method explained in the question is still valid. What problem do you have?

Comment: It looks like it was moved to MonkeyRunner.loadImageFromFile(PATH) . Apparently looks to be undocumented as well.

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) allows you to obtain the screenshot of the entire screen or specific Views. These screenshots are usually written to a file using

```
View.writeImageToFile(self, filename, format="PNG")
```

However, if you are interested in obtaining the primitive image object, which is a `PIL Image` (see http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), you can do

```
image = device.takeSnapshot()
```

and then manipulate or analyze it as per your needs using the available [methods and tools](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) in the library.

Comment: So... In pseudocode... 1. save image to file 2. use im.getcolors(maxcolors) to get list of all colors in image 3. iterate through the list to find a particular color. This is a workaround and I bet it will be slow. I am still searching for a way to check whether a certain bigger image consists of smaller predefined image (like button).

Comment: As I mentioned, you don't have to save the file as you can obtain the `Image` object and you can obtain that `Image` for a single `View` (i.e. `Button`).